# How much were the LMs maneuvered to their landing points?

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-landing, lunar-module

The story of the Apollo 11 landing includes Armstrong having to fly the LM beyond a boulder field at the automatically targeted site. Was this essentially continuing along the same track the LM had followed through its descent, or was there some lateral deviation as well? The LM had six degrees of freedom (3 axes of both rotation and translation, although having only limited forward view, it would not have been wise to fly it "sideways" or "backwards" i.e. blind). What I am interested in is whether Armstrong (or any of the pilots of the subsequent missions) executed any  significant "pirouette" or lateral translation maneuvers to locate and fly to their chosen landing sites and/or pirouette to fully inspect a site before touchdown. If not, was it purely unnecessary, was it inadvisable due to stability concerns, inadvisable due to fuel management concerns... ?

Comment: See the related [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37488/how-far-off-did-apollo-11-land/37489#37489) about Apollo 11.

Answer (score 10):

The excellent [monograph](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19720018205.pdf) by my former colleague Floyd Bennett has this information on Apollo 11 and 12.

Here are the Apollo 11 and 12 ground tracks showing lateral maneuvering.

[image]

[image]

Apologies for poor image quality.

Some debrief remarks by Pete Conrad - the groundtrack looks like he flew around Surveyor Crater, and sure enough:

> I saw  a suitable  landing  area between  the Surveyor crater and head
>   crater,   which  now meant  **I  had to  maneuver to  my  left  and
>   sort  of fly around  the side  of the  crater**,  which  I  started
>   to I guess  I  wheeled  it  pretty hard,  because Al  commented  a
>   couple of times that  I  was really cranking her around  and  I told
>   him it  was no  problem. I  had  everything  under control and I  did
>   increase  the  rate  of descent after he  called my  attention  to
>   the  fact that  we  had leveled off quite high  at 500 feet.

From [here](http://I%20saw%20%20a%20suitable%20%20landing%20%20area%20between%20%20the%20Surveyor%20crater%20and%20head%20%20crater%20,%20%20%20which%20%20now%20meant%20%20I%20%20had%20to%20%20maneuver%20to%20%20my%20%20left%20%20and%20sort%20%20of%20fly%20around%20%20the%20side%20%20of%20the%20%20crater%20,%20%20which%20%20I%20%20started%20to%20L%20%209-ll%20CONRAD%20do%20.%20%20%20I%20guess%20%20I%20%20wheeled%20%20it%20%20pretty%20hard,%20%20because%20Al%20%20commented%20%20a%20(CONT'D)%20couple%20of%20times%20that%20%20I%20%20was%20really%20cranking%20her%20around%20%20and%20%20I%20told%20him%20it%20%20was%20no%20%20problem.%20I%20%20had%20%20everything%20%20under%20control%20and%20I%20%20did%20increase%20%20the%20%20rate%20%20of%20descent%20after%20he%20%20called%20my%20%20atten-tion%20%20to%20the%20%20fact%20that%20%20we%20%20had%20leveled%20off%20quite%20high%20%20at%20500%20feet.), emphasis mine

Note "head crater" refers to the Snowman formation:

[image]

From [here](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/a12_site1234_locations.jpg)

Comment: just asked [How “hard” did Apollo 12 turn left just before it landed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37734/12102)

Answer (score 7):

> What I am interested in is whether Armstrong (or any of the pilots of the subsequent missions) executed any significant "pirouette" or lateral translation maneuvers to locate and fly to their chosen landing sites and/or pirouette to fully inspect a site before touchdown. If not, was it purely unnecessary, was it inadvisable due to stability concerns, inadvisable due to fuel management concerns... ?

None of the LMs did anything like a "pirouette". There was some lateral maneuvering during the P64 phase, where the commander can alter the computer's projected landing site, and on the final approach (as you can see from Apollo 11's ~400 feet of crossrange during the manual P66 mode in Organic Marble's answer), but in general, they tried to stay moving generally forward. The limits on fuel prevented doing a full survey of an intended landing site, and the lack of any side view made it very unsafe to fly at low altitude with significant lateral or backward velocity.

If the immediately available terrain for landing was unfavorable, it was much safer to "go long", maintain vertical hover and forward velocity, and look for something better.

Answer (score 6):

See Apollo by the Numbers page 35:

[image]

There is no information about the maneuvered distance to avoid obstacles, only the distance between planned and actual landing spot.
From the [Apollo 11 Summary](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_11a_Summary.htm), link from called2voyage:

> The 756.39-second powered descent engine burn was initiated at
>   102:33:05.01. The time was as planned, but the position at which
>   powered descent initiation occurred was about 4 n mi farther downrange
>   than expected. This resulted in the landing point being shifted
>   downrange about 4 n mi.
>
> The LM was maneuvered manually 1,100 feet down range from the
>   preplanned landing point during the final 2.5 minutes of descent.

The minimum distance was acheived by Apollo 14 with 55 feet north and 165 feet east, using Pythagoras 174 feet.