# What was the procedure for Lunar Orbit Rendezvous?

Tags: apollo-program, history, rendezvous

I've read the following questions:

- [Why was orbital rendezvous considered so controversial?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29865/why-was-orbital-rendezvous-considered-so-controversial/29868#29868)
- [Could an Apollo LM land uncrewed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21620/could-an-apollo-lm-land-uncrewed)
- [How "hard" did Apollo 12 turn left just before it landed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37734/how-hard-did-apollo-12-turn-left-just-before-it-landed)

And considering that the landing site could vary based on local terrain, and the overall degree of manual control available to the crew, I'm curious about the procedure for Lunar Orbit Rendezvous.

I know that a Rendezvous is a matter of matching orbital parameters, but how did the crew in the LM determine when to make their ascent, what trajectory to take, and how to coordinate their orbit with the CM?

Comment: They had a rendezvous radar within the LM to measure distance to the CSM as well as relative speed. There were rendezvous guidance programms on the LM computer.

Comment: I think the question is more about: how did they know when it was time to launch, and once they did what happened?